# Django: Django_filters in a class-based views

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I ask you if you know how put this filters :

```
class CoursesFilters(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model   =  Courses
        exclude = ('description')
```

in this class view :

```
class CoursesList(ListView):
    model         = Courses    
    template_name = 'courses_list.html'
```

I used to build my applications using function-based views, and this is my first time use class-based views.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`django-filters` has a [**`FilterView`** [readthedocs.io]](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html#generic-view-configuration) that can be used:

```
from django_filters.views import FilterView

class CoursesList(FilterView):
    model = Courses    
    template_name = 'courses_list.html' 
    filterset_class = CoursesFilters
```

The `filterset_class` specifies the `FilterSet` that. The filter is passed to the template as `filter`. You thus can render a `{{ filter.form }}` in the template.

Answer (score 0):

```py
class CoursesList(ListView):
    model = Courses    
    template_name = 'courses_list.html'
 
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs: any):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter'] = CoursesFilters(self.request.GET, 
        queryset=self.get_queryset())
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.object.courses_set.all()
```

courses_list.html

```
{{ filter.form.as_p }}
```